# Create an excutable jar in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, jar, intellij-idea, executable-jar

I am using IntelliJ IDEA 12.1.3. I have one module and I am trying to convert it into a jar as per the steps given [here](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2010/08/quickly-create-jar-artifact/). I built the jar file and I moved the jar file to D:/. If I try to run this jar I get the following message:

> Failed to load Main-Class manifest attribute from jar

If I run it using `java -classpath jar com.code.TestCase` it works perfectly.

Why does this happen? I created the jar using IntelliJ IDEA. In that jar it has all the code for all external libraries which I added.

In the src manifest file:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: com.code.TestCase
```

but the jar's manifest file content is:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Build-Jdk: 1.6.0
Built-By: ubuntu
Created-By: Apache Maven
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver

Name: org.apache.log4j
Implementation-Vendor: "Apache Software Foundation"
Implementation-Title: log4j
Implementation-Version: 1.2.15
```

Why is `Main-Class` not added in the jar file MANIFEST.MF, but it has `Main-Class` in src?

Comment: Intellij Idea *1*? or did you mean perhaps 11, 12 or 13...

Comment: Can u share your `com.code.TestCase` class? It should have the main method

Comment: @vikingsteve It is 12.1.3

Comment: @ArunKumar I n that Testcase Class i have main method only

Comment: @muthu silly question - have u looked at the date/time on the artifact? it *is* being built when you *make* it, right? no weird file encodings on your manifest?

Comment: @vikingsteve.Ya i looked the date/ time it is created when i built the application and it has no wierd file  encoding

Answer (score 54):

I have experienced the same issue and found a fix and/or bug in how Intellij auto populates the path for the manifest.

**INTELLIJ UI**

When creating an artifact to create jar files, IntelliJ auto populates the the path where the current manifest is located.

i.e. After choosing Main-Class in the artifact creation page, Intellij will add automatically the following path \src\java\META-INF\MANIFEST.MF. For some reason, the build command never takes the mentioned MANIFEST.MF File. It creates one from scratch without the Main-Class definition which results on the "Failed to load Main-Class"

If using the IntelliJ UI to create jar artifacts; removed the auto populate path by changing it to `/$PROJECT_DIR/src/` and click OK.

Example of what it looks like by default:

[image: default intellij jar artifact settings]

Now this is what it should look like after the change:

[image: fixed intellij artifact settings]

**MANUAL FIX TO ENTER CORRECT MANIFEST.MF FILE**

On the IntelliJ project , open .idea\artifacts\_jar.xml

Make sure it contains

```
  <element id="directory" name="META-INF">
    <element id="file-copy" path="$PROJECT_DIR$/src/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF" />
  </element>
```

You might need to reload intelliJ once you do this so it picks up on the changes to the .xml file

For me it happened on maven projects where a different structure exists (i.e. src/main/java/..).

I am using OSX 10.9.2 with IntelliJ version 12.1.6

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for posting this. Was looking all over for a solution and trying to understand why it didn't work

Comment: Best answer on this problem!

Comment: Thank you BRO) Thats definately time saver post

Answer (score 0):

One of the important rule is that Manifest file must end with new line or carriage return character. If it is not there then add now.

Comment: but it is created by intellij IDEA

Comment: The default manifest created by IDEA 12.1.3 has a blank line at the end.

Answer (score 0):

May be this blog will help you.

http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2013/01/how-to-fix-failed-to-load-main-class-manifest-attribute-jar-java-eclipse.html