# IntelliJ correctly using Libraries

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar

I'm using `IntelliJ` without a build tool for a project, I build it as a `jar`.

Now I'm using the `iText` library for PDF(s), if I put all the `iText` jars into a folder and add it in `IntelliJ`, I can use the `iText` functions and if the program works, I add `iText` as dependency and set it in Build Artifacts for the `Jar`, but if I build it, it just copies the compiled `iText` jar into my jar, so the program doesn't work.

How do I include the Library correctly in the `jar`, without a build tool?

Comment: When you say "without a build tool", do you mean something like ant?

Comment: Yes, I just build it with the default compiler.

Comment: How do you test your jar? What is your execution command? And could you clear that what do you mean by "copying the compiled iText jar to my jar". When you open your jar with a package manager (like Winrar) you see iText.jar in your jar or you see iText's packages in your jar?

Comment: I run it with IntelliJ Run, Application, and then just the Main class, and in before launch it does make. I have a itextpdf (compiled), and a source edition, if I open my jar I see my programm with it's packages and a copy of the compiled itextpdf-5.5.6 jar.

Comment: Could this solve your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20952713/wrong-manifest-mf-in-intellij-idea-created-jar

Comment: Also, please add more than "the program doesn't work" to descriptions.  Does it throw an exception (`ClassNotFoundException`)? Does it run but doesn't spit out the correct output?  I think you get the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `Project Structure` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>) `> Artifacts > + > Jar > From Modules with dependencies`

Select your module and the main class. Select `Extract to the target JAR` if you want to bundle all your libraries into one file.

Close the dialog and check (or change) the output folder - that's where your JAR will be created.

Now go to `Build > Build Artifacts` and select the artifact you just created.

[Reference](http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2010/08/quickly-create-jar-artifact/)