# Java manifest file invalid after exporting project

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

When exporting a project into a jar file in intellij the content of the **META-INF/MANIFEST.MF** file is altered and no longer contains the entry point(main class) even though the **source/main/java/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF** contains a valid entry point:

```
$ cat META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: org.fiware.kiara.generator.kiaragen
```

The project directory looks like:

[image: kiaragen_MANIFEST]

where MANIFEST.MF is the (valid) manifest file. Upon creation of an artifact the correct meta directory is picked:

[image: kiara_artifact]

Unpacking the exported .jar file shows a manifest file with a completely different content:

```
$ jar xf kiaragen.jar
cat META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Implementation-Title: Some Vendor
Implementation-Version: 1.0.1
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Built-By: ub
Specification-Vendor: Some Vendor
Specification-Title: Some Vendor
Implementation-Vendor-Id:
Created-By: Apache Maven
Build-Jdk: 1.6.0_29
Specification-Version: 1.0.1
Implementation-Vendor: Some Vendor
```

Where does Intellij find this information and why does it remove the Main-Class entry point?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20952713/wrong-manifest-mf-in-intellij-idea-created-jar is this duplicate?

Comment: MANIFEST indeed have its place in `resources` not `sources`