# IntelliJ build wrong JAR: Could not find or load main class

Tags: class, intellij-idea, jar, program-entry-point

I have a simple example

```java
public class FileSystemReadFile {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Reading the file" + args[0]);
    }
}
```

which is created in IntelliJ where I want to build JAR file; So what I did:

1. Added Artifact with dependencies (presumably I have some);
2. Ensure that `MANIFEST.MF` is located in `src\main\resources\META-INF\` as it is already mentioned somewhere here on the site.
3. Run Artifact build which gave me JAR file in out folder and I run that jar file that said me "Could not find or load main class" 
    `java <name>.jar`

You may see that main class is added into MANIFEST and location of manifest is also fine.

[image: Project structure]

When I open that created JAR file, I see the same MANIFEST content, I see lots of dependency modules, but I don't see my class!

[image]

I suspect that is a cause. Any ideas?

Comment: Your class is the fifth file from the bottom in your screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what was with IntellJ, but I rebuilded artifacts again and it was ok.

```
hadoop jar <Jar-name>
java -jar <Jar-name>
```

Everything is working fine.

Comment: Thanks for posting solution

Comment: I get the error "no main manifest attribute, in jarname.jar"
I found solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20952713/wrong-manifest-mf-in-intellij-idea-created-jar

Answer (score 5):

If you include any signed JARs in your app and then use IntelliJ to build artifacts, it will extract the JARS and bundle them with your compiled output.

This then causes a JAVA security exception. I've seen this with Eclipse Paho and Bouncy Castle which are signed.

You can check if any of the library JARs you are using are signed using the jarsigner tool.

```
jarsigner -verify -verbose  <path to library JAR>
```

Change your IntelliJ artifact setup so that these get bundled as libraries instead of being extracted. Extraction invalidates the certificate as you'd expect.

[image: See how Paho and BCP are not extracted during artifact creation]

Try creating a dummy project with just Main. Add 1 library JAR (that you are trying to build with) at a time. Build an output JAR each time until Main breaks. That's how I found this.

IntelliJ should warn you.....