# Can't run .jar because "no main manifest attribute"

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, jar, executable-jar

I've never built an executable .jar before, and I'm trying to do so with a Maven project with IntelliJ, and I can't seem to run the program. I've done it through the Project Structure -> artifacts route, and I've set the main class and locations properly or so I thought, in the configuration:

in my **pom.xml**

```
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>repackage</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <classifier>spring-boot</classifier>
                    <mainClass>
                        app.ContactRunner
                    </mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

And here's a screenshot of the project structure along with the `MANIFEST.MF`

[image: Screenshot]

What's missing that I need to add in order to execute this jar? Thanks for the help!

**EDIT-=-=-=**

I have removed the packaging structure, and it is now just `app.ContactRunner` with nothing extra in the MANIFEST file.

Comment: Try to remove src.main.java.app from the main class, this does not look like a valid classpath.

Comment: It was originally `app.ContactRunner` but that didn't work.

Comment: Also, it won't allow me to fully remove it all, `app` still needs to be in there.

Comment: If you open the jar file (it's just a zip file with another extension) and look at the `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file, does *it* have the `Main-Class` attribute?

Comment: It does not. This was automatically generated though. How do I re-zip it back into a .jar file?

Comment: `src.main.java` is not part of the package name and should **not** be included in the fully qualified classname. Check the `package ...` definition at the top of that source file.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I took that out and changed it to just `app.ContactRunner`, still same issue

Comment: I don't use IntelliJ, but the hint "*You are editing a file which is ignored*" seems to indicate that IntelliJ (or your Maven build) generates the manifest in a different way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to move where the MANIFEST folder was. It was putting it under

`/src/main/java/`

and it needed to be under

`/src/main/resources`

As taken from this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/21074091/7082628