# "No auto configuration classes found in META-INF/spring.factories"

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, deployment, jar, vaadin-spring-boot

I developed a vaadin spring boot application in intellij idea.

When trying to run the jar-file I keep getting the following error:

"No auto configuration classes found in META-INF/spring.factories"

---

Minimal example:

Using SpringInitializr (https://start.spring.io), in a few seconds one can create a mini-app to replicate the problem. The SpringInitializr tags used are: "Web" and "Vaadin".

CAREFUL (!!!) when creating the jar-file: there's a bug in intellij idea ... remove the auto populate path for the manifest file by changing it to /$PROJECT_DIR/src/ , see answer by mgrandi here:

[Create an excutable jar in IntelliJ IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17024715/create-an-excutable-jar-in-intellij-idea/23142480#23142480)

When running the app using

```
 java -jar minimalExample.jar
```

you will get the following error message:

"No auto configuration classes found in META-INF/spring.factories"

How can I get rid of this error message?

P.S.:

Here's the pom file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>minEx</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>minEx</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <vaadin.version>8.1.0</vaadin.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

P.P.S.: the suggestions here didn't work:

[SpringBoot - making jar files - No auto configuration classes found in META-INF/spring.factories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38792031/springboot-making-jar-files-no-auto-configuration-classes-found-in-meta-inf)

**************************UPDATE*****************************************

When trying to build the application using the command

```
mvn package
```

I'm getting the following error message:

```
INFO] Building minEx 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.1.11 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ minEx ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ minEx ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ minEx ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/username/Desktop/minEx/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ minEx ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test (default-test) @ minEx ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: /Users/username/Desktop/minEx/target/surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Failed to instantiate SLF4J LoggerFactory
Reported exception:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ch/qos/logback/core/joran/spi/JoranException
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:150)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:124)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:412)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:357)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:155)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:132)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:273)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.<clinit>(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:96)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runner.Computer.getRunner(Computer.java:40)
    at org.junit.runner.Computer$1.runnerForClass(Computer.java:31)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.runners(RunnerBuilder.java:101)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.runners(RunnerBuilder.java:87)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.<init>(Suite.java:81)
    at org.junit.runner.Computer.getSuite(Computer.java:28)
    at org.junit.runner.Request.classes(Request.java:75)
    at org.junit.runner.Request.classes(Request.java:91)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.common.junit4.JUnit4Reflector.createRequest(JUnit4Reflector.java:63)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.common.junit4.JUnit4ProviderUtil.createSuiteDescription(JUnit4ProviderUtil.java:113)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.createTestsDescription(JUnit4Provider.java:257)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:124)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:203)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:155)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.JoranException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 36 more
Running com.example.minEx.MinExApplicationTests
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.021 sec <<< FAILURE! - in com.example.minEx.MinExApplicationTests
initializationError(com.example.minEx.MinExApplicationTests)  Time elapsed: 0.018 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:283)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:203)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:155)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)


Results :

Tests in error: 
  MinExApplicationTests.initializationError » NoClassDefFound Could not initiali...

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.587 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-11-02T20:34:41+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 19M/178M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test (default-test) on project minEx: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to /Users/username/Desktop/minEx/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Comment: Did you consider [using Maven to build the jar](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-maven-plugin.html)?

Comment: Thank you for your comment ... when I try that I'm getting a different kind of error message, see the "UPDATE" part of my edited post.

Comment: sorry ... I misread ("run" instead of "build") ... I tried to build the jar file using "mvn package" ... I'm getting some other error in this case (see updated post above)

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by deleting and then recreating the maven repository folder (inside the .m2 folder) .

Then I ran

```
mvn package
```

and got a build success !

Answer (score 0):

For me, even after deleting .m2 folder it didn't work.

1. I added spring.factories in resources folder of the project(i.e. add this file in the buildPath of the project).
2. Also, I added below line in application.properties

   ```
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=\
   ```